# Hide all sibilings of a DIV when mouse enter/hover to a link and Show the particular DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have separated buttons and DIV's representing each button. I need to show only the particular DIV when hover or mouse enter on it's corresponding button. The code is shown below,

```
  <ul class="icon-list">
    <li><a href="#" id="btn-ftr-5"><div class="circle"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3"></i></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="btn-ftr-4"><div class="circle"><i class="fa fa-tasks fa-3"></i></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="btn-ftr-3"><div class="circle"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-3"></i></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="btn-ftr-2"><div class="circle"><i class="fa fa-music fa-3"></i></div></a></li>
   </ul>
```

And the DIVs is below,

```
<div class="row feature-content-original" id="ftr-1">
  <div class="col-md-5 feature-title" id="#title-ftr">
    <h2>Event Details</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 feature-info">
    <p>Welcome to your NuEvents Snapshot page.
       From your event management snapshot page, you can get a quick overview of al
      l your event statistics. Monitor your RSVP/Food/Drink/Song activity in real time.
       From your Snapshot page you can create a new task, memo, or appointment with ease.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row feature-content hidden" id="ftr-2">
  <div class="col-md-5 feature-title" id="#title-ftr">
      <h2>Food And Drinks</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7 feature-info">
    <p>From your event management snapshot page, you can get a quick overview of al
   l your event statistics. Monitor your RSVP/Food/Drink/Song activity in real time.
    From your Snapshot page you can create a new task, memo,
    your RSVP/Food/Drink/Song activity in real time.
     From your Snapshot page you can create a new task, memor appointment with ease.</p>
  </div>
</div> <!--etc -->
```

And I have 2 classes for DIVs to show and hide as 'showftr' and 'hidden'

The following code is not working. I need your help to get a result.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#btn-ftr-2').mouseenter(function() {
 $('#ftr-2').addClass('showftr');
}, function() {
 $('#ftr-2').removeClass('hidden');
}, function(){
 $('#ftr-2').sibilings().addClass('hidden');
}
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: I have 10 links and 10 DIVs ftr-2 also here and I have mistaken not to post my whole code here. sorry for it!

Comment: you can add some additional classes to the html isn't it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yyq86vtj/ ?

Comment: I dont get it. I tried to hide all sibilings of DIV 2 when mouse enter link 2

Comment: Side note: why you are passing multiple functions to `mouseenter` (which takes only one handler function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like that?

### DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Lyadfdgf/1/

Use the same button's id and div's class to be shown/hidden.
You can get show/hide funtion with the jquery script alone.

#### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.feature-content').hide(0);
    $('.feature-content').eq(0).show(0);

    $('.icon-list li a').on('mouseover', function () {
        $('.feature-content').hide(0);
        var get_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.feature-content.'+get_id).show(0);
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<ul class="icon-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="div-ftr-5"><div class="circle"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3"></i> Event Detail</div></a>
    </li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
<div class="row feature-content div-ftr-5">
    <div class="col-md-5 feature-title" id="#title-ftr">
         <h2>Event Details</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 feature-info">
        <p>Welcome to your NuEvents Snapshot page. From your event management snapshot page, you can get a quick overview of al l your event statistics. Monitor your RSVP/Food/Drink/Song activity in real time. From your Snapshot page you can create a new task, memo, or appointment with ease.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!--etc -->
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. my approach was completely wrong. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I made a little bit changes not to use same IDs, please use class for div (to be shown/hidden) instead of ID. Check the updated demo again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt, if I understood it correctly:

```
$('a[id^=btn-ftr-]').hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf('-') + 1, id.length);
    $('div[id^=ftr-]').removeClass('showftr').addClass('hidden');
    $('div[id=ftr-' + id + ']').removeClass('hidden').addClass('showftr');
}, function() {
    $('div[id^=ftr-]').removeClass('hidden').addClass('showftr');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. this will help. But the issue is sibillings are not hidden still.

Comment: they should now. try this code again. I just modified a few things.

Comment: yup Thank you for the help!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, can you select it as the right answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a repeated structure, you can simplify your code by adding additional common classes to the elements

A class `btn-ftr` is added to all buttons where as a class `ftr` is added to all the div's.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $contents = $('.ftr')
  $('.btn-ftr').hover(function() {
    var tid = this.id.replace('btn-', ''),
      $target = $('#' + tid);
    $contents.not($target).addClass('hidden');
    $target.addClass('showftr').removeClass('hidden');
  }, function() {
    $contents.filter('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
    var tid = this.id.replace('btn-', '');
    $('#' + tid).removeClass('showftr');
  })

})
```

```css
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul class="icon-list">
    <li><a href="#" id="btn-ftr-1" class="btn-ftr"><div class="circle"><i class="fa fa-user fa-3"></i></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="btn-ftr-2" class="btn-ftr"><div class="circle"><i class="fa fa-tasks fa-3"></i></div></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="row feature-content-original ftr" id="ftr-1">
    <div class="col-md-5 feature-title" id="#title-ftr">
        <h2>Event Details</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 feature-info">
        <p>Welcome to your NuEvents Snapshot page.
            From your event management snapshot page, you can get a quick overview of al
            l your event statistics. Monitor your RSVP/Food/Drink/Song activity in real time.
            From your Snapshot page you can create a new task, memo, or appointment with ease.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row feature-content hidden ftr" id="ftr-2">
    <div class="col-md-5 feature-title" id="#title-ftr">
        <h2>Food And Drinks</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 feature-info">
        <p>From your event management snapshot page, you can get a quick overview of al
            l your event statistics. Monitor your RSVP/Food/Drink/Song activity in real time.
            From your Snapshot page you can create a new task, memo,
            your RSVP/Food/Drink/Song activity in real time.
            From your Snapshot page you can create a new task, memor appointment with ease.</p>
    </div>
</div> <!--etc -->
```